# Como mostrar uma Activity de chamada quando o dispositivo está bloqueado e com a tela desligada

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo uma app de Vídeo e Voz.

O que eu preciso é mostrar uma activity the requisição de chamada quando um usuário tenta ligar para o outro.

Eu já estou usando o Firebase Cloud Message para enviar push messages para o device, avisando ele que tem uma requisição de chamada.

Mas estou enfrentando alguns problemas tentando acordar o device e mostrar na frente da lock screen a activity de chamada para que o usuário aceite ou rejeite a chamada.

O que estou tentando fazer é parecido com o que o **Whats App** faz quando recebe uma chamada.

[image: Foto de uma chamada do WhatsApp sendo recebida]

Mostrar isso quando o device está unlocked e a app esta em foreground não é dificil, minha dificuldade está exatamente em mostrar isso quando o device está locked e em rest mode (tela preta).

Comment: Bom dia meu caro! Você sabe que irá enfrentar muitos problema se trantando disso? Aconselho você a dar uma olhada no [Q-municate](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android), que utiliza o [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/). Faz o download dele e importa um projeto e estude bastante ele. Com toda certeza vai aprender muita coisa.

Comment: Você quer que, em vez de aparecer a notificação, seja aberta um Activity?

Comment: @ramaral sim seria isso mesmo, imagino que a exemplo dessa imagem do whatsapp, seja uma activity e não uma simples notificação. Pois existem muitas ações que podem ser tomadas a partir dessa tela e se atender ela tem que dar um unlock no device e abrir a app para realizar a chamada

Comment: Eu nunca usei o whatsapp, ela aparece sem intervenção do usuário? Pode colocar o código que a sua app usa para a nitivicação?

Comment: Basicamente o que ocorre no whats app é o seguinte. Se você faz uma chamada (call) para outro usuário do whats app, essa tela é apresentada para responder a chamada (aceitando ou rejeitando ela).
E essa tela da imagem que coloquei é apresentada exatamente assim, mesmo quando o device está bloqueado e em repouso.

Comment: Infelizmente não vou poder postar o código agora, não tenho acesso a ele nesse momento.

Answer (score 0):

Umas das coisas que você precisa saber é basicamente [Executar um Serviço em segundo plano no Android](http://www.klebermota.eti.br/2011/11/08/executando-um-servico-em-segundo-plano-no-android/). Lembrando que para criar um serviço, você deve criar um sub-classe de `Service` que em sua implementação, você precisa sobrecarregar alguns métodos de chamada que manipulam aspectos chave do [ciclo de vida](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html?hl=pt-br)  do serviço e fornecem mecanismos para que os componentes se conectem ao serviço como mostra também no diagrama lá em baixo.

> Um serviço está na forma “Started” quando um componente da aplicação
>   (como uma Atividade) inicia-o pela chamada a startService().

Você sabe que irá enfrentar muitos problema se tratando disso? Pois então, aconselho você a dar uma olhada no [Q-municate](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android), que é um projeto [Open Source](http://canaltech.com.br/o-que-e/o-que-e/O-que-e-open-source/) super bacana que que utiliza como base o [Quickblox](https://quickblox.com/). Faça o download dele e importa um projeto e estude bastante ele. Com toda certeza vai aprender muita coisa.

Dê uma observada neste diagrama que no caminho de retorno existem vários retornos diferentes de outros métodos se tratando de Service Api.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @cleidimar-viana, obrigado pelo resposta. Porém eu já recebo as notificações via Firebase Cloud Message. Por tanto o minha app mesmo com o device locked e em modo de descanso recebe notificações. O que eu preciso é a partir disso fazer a implementação da minha dúvida postada aqui. Para isso não preciso de um Service rodando o tempo todo para minha app.

Comment: @ErickGallani como comentei na resposta, você pode dar uma lida em [Executar um Serviço em segundo plano](http://www.klebermota.eti.br/2011/11/08/executando-um-servico-em-segundo-plano-no-android/). Este artigo é tradução de um artigo disponibilizado pelo próprio Google e talvez irá te ajudar bastante na implementação. Boa Sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Julgo o que você procura é uma das novas funcionalidades introduzidas pelo Lollipop(API21) no sistema de notificações.

Fazendo uso da nova propriedade [visibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#visibility), da classe *Notification*, é possível indicar ao sistema quando e como ele deve revelar a presença e conteúdo duma notificação.

Há 3 tipos de "visibilidade":

- **Secreta** (Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET) - A notificação é considerada sensível e não é mostrada no *"lock screen"*. Este é o comportamento por defeito(padrão).
- **Privada** (Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE) - A notificação é considerada sensível apenas no que diz respeito ao conteúdo. Ela é apresentada no *"lock screen"* mas o conteúdo da mensagem é substituído por *"Contents hidden"*.
- **Publica** (Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) - A notificação é considerada não sensível e a notificação é totalmente mostrada no *"lock screen"*

A propriedade pode ser "setada" usando o *Notification.Builder*.

```
Notification notification  = new Notification.Builder(this)
  .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
  .setContentTitle(title)
  .setContentText(text)
  .setSmallIcon(icon)
  .setAutoCancel(true)
  .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC).build();
NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notification );
```

**Nota**: Esta propriedade só está disponível a partir da API21. A *appcompat* torna-a acessível e pode ser usada, mas o seu efeito só é sentido em dispositivo com *Android* 5 ou superior.

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas, mas o que eu acho que se adequada mais ao que estou querendo fazer é isso aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-to-display-activity-when-the-screen-is-locked